# Query to output results in one row for all combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert the output to one row from multiple columns. How should I update the attached code.
This is my current output:

```
OrigSamp    DupSamp1
23407   23414
23420   23424
23420   23430
23420   23431
```

This is the expected output I want i.e. for every value in the first column OrigSamp, the relevant values in cols 2,3,4 should be in the same row. If no value then return NULL.

```
OrigSamp    DupSamp1    DupSamp2    DupSamp3
23407       23414       NULL        NULL
23420       23424       23430       23431
```

My code below: Any help is appreciated.

```
declare @tbl table(OrigSamp int, DupSamp1 int, OrigRes varChar(10), DupRes1 varChar(10))

INSERT INTO @tbl
(OrigSamp,DupSamp1,OrigRes, DupRes1 )
SELECT 
s.SAMPLE_NUMBER as [OrigSamp]
,s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER  as [DupSamp1]
,r.FORMATTED_ENTRY as [OrigRes]
,r1.FORMATTED_ENTRY  as [DupRes1]
FROM 
SAMPLE s
INNER JOIN SAMPLE s1 on s.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s1.PARENT_SAMPLE
INNER JOIN RESULT r on s.SAMPLE_NUMBER = r.SAMPLE_NUMBER
INNER JOIN RESULT r1 on r1.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER
WHERE
s.LOCATION = 'TAURANGA' 
and s.STATUS = 'C' and s1.STATUS = 'C'
and s1.SAMPLE_NAME = 'DUP' 
and s.PARENT_SAMPLE = 0
and r.ANALYSIS in ('BC-B19_ISSUE_6-CENTR','BCPSD-ASTM_C136-CENTR')
and r1.ANALYSIS in ('BC-B19_ISSUE_6-CENTR','BCPSD-ASTM_C136-CENTR')
and r.NAME = 'Bitumen content'
and r1.NAME = 'Bitumen content'

declare @pivotcols varchar(200) = (STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.rn) 
FROM (select *
, 'DupSamp' + cast(ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by OrigSamp order by OrigSamp) as varchar)rn
from
@tbl) c
            
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,''))

declare @query varchar(max);

select * 
into #temp1 
from @tbl

set @query =  
'select OrigSamp,' + @pivotcols + ' from
(select OrigSamp,DupSamp1 as [samp1],''DupSamp'' 
+ cast(ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by OrigSamp order by OrigSamp) as varchar)rn
from
#temp1
)t
pivot
(
max(samp1) for rn in (' +  @pivotcols + ')
)p'

exec(@query)

drop table #temp1

Current output with the above code:
OrigSamp DupSamp1 DupSamp2  DupSamp3
23420     23424     23430   23431                                                                     

required output      
OrigSamp DupSamp1 DupSamp2 DupSamp3 OrigRes DupRes1 DupRes2 DupRes3
23420    23424   23430     23431    6.2     6.9     6.1     6.6
```

Comment: `I tried PIVOT() but not too successful.` Please show your pivot query too

Comment: I tweaked you question so the images are visible without clicking. You may want to learn how that is done - but images are often not useful to us.

Comment: WHY one row? What is the purpose for putting all on one row? e.g. what happens if the current result is 20 rows? or 200 rows? Also; if this is for consumption via a webpage or report then SQL may not be the best place to achieve this output style. NB: If there is a fixed number of columns then please also tell us what that number is.

Comment: @SQLKG - Please add any code [to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71522151/edit). Also, you'll get better responses if you take the time to post a [complete, self-contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  That means posting the table structure and a few sample rows *as text*, not an image.  There are tools that make it very easy to do, such as https://dbfiddle.uk/ or http://sqlfiddle.com/ (which has a "Text to DLL" option, which lets you paste tabular data and generates the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements automatically.)

Comment: @Dale K , minimum code below.
 SELECT 
        s.SAMPLE_NUMBER as [OrigSamp]
        ,s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER  as [DupSamp1]
FROM 
        SAMPLE s
        INNER JOIN SAMPLE s1 on s.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s1.PARENT_SAMPLE
WHERE
        s.LOCATION = 'TAURANGA' 
        and s.STATUS = 'C' and s1.STATUS = 'C'
        and s1.SAMPLE_NAME = 'DUP' 
        and s.PARENT_SAMPLE = 0
 output
OrigSampDupSamp1
23407 23414
23420 23424
23420 23430
23420 2343
 expected
OrigSamp DupSamp1 DupSamp2 DupSamp3
23407  23414     NULL        NULL
23420 23424     23430        23431

Comment: @Dale Have updated my original question with the minimal code. Does that help?

Comment: @Paul Maxwell, one row for each value in the first column. The first column is the parent sample. The other columns are the child. So i need one row for each parent and their corresponding children. Parent and child are determined by the field SAMPLE.SAMPLE_NAME.

Comment: @Dale K Have updated the formatted. Is it better?

Comment: Updated the current data set. Thanks for that Dale.

Comment: Is the maximum number of "DupSamp" columns known? If so, what is the maximum number?

Comment: If you assign sequence numbers to the dups under each parent using something like `Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.SAMPLE_NUMBER ORDER BY s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER)`, you can then `GROUP BY s.SAMPLE_NUMBER` and use *conditional aggregation* to build up the result with expressions like `DupSamp1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence = 1 THEN DupSamp END), DupSamp2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Sequence = 2 THEN DupSamp END), ...`

Comment: @SOS Max number of DupSamp i will have is 5 i.e. there Should be DupSamp1, DupSamp2, DupSamp3, DupSamp4, DupSamp5 columns for each OrigSamp.  Some of them may have null values

Comment: @ T N I will give this a go and get back on the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring the desired output using dynamic pivot operation.

Try the below sample out.

```
declare @tbl table(OrigSamp int, DupSamp1 int)

insert into @tbl
values(23407,23414)
,(23420,23424)
,(23420,23430)
,(23420,23431)

declare @pivotcols varchar(200) = (STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.rn) 
            FROM (select *
            , 'DupSamp' + cast(ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by OrigSamp order by OrigSamp) as varchar)rn
            from
            @tbl) c
            
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,''))

declare @query varchar(max);

select * 
into #temp1 
from @tbl

set @query =  
'select OrigSamp,' + @pivotcols + ' from
(select OrigSamp,DupSamp1 as [samp1],''DupSamp'' 
+ cast(ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by OrigSamp order by OrigSamp) as varchar)rn
from
#temp1
)t
pivot
(
max(samp1) for rn in (' +  @pivotcols + ')
)p'

exec(@query)

drop table #temp1
```

Comment: I have amended the code (in my question) as suggested by you. I have one more request: How do i update code to show more columns - please see my code and the ensuing current and required output at the end. Appreciate your help. GH

Comment: @SQLKG Coder's query is "dynamic" so the number of columns will expand or contract as required by the data, and that code is designed to meet the original sample data and expected result (which it does do) see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a966c0bdd57e08e1c8295ceb7b33f434  **You have moved the goalposts** and added `OrigRes DupRes1 DupRes2 DupRes3` to the expected result but you have no explanation of how or why those columns now exist. If you want to ask another question go ahead but the original question has been answered

Comment: @Paul In that case i will try with the additional columns using the code provided by Coder1991. How do i acknowledge that my original question is answered. I am pretty new to asking questions in Stack.